# MS Access date diff from one row and previous row of different fields

Tags: ms-access-2010

I need to find the difference in weeks from marked Previous End Date and next Start Date.

```
Visit Type  |   Start Date  |   End Date    |   Weeks since previous visit
------------+---------------+---------------+------------------------------
Check-Up    |   19-Jan-15   |   19-Feb-15   |
Check-Up    |   27-Jan-15   |   27-Jan-15   |   xxx   
Check-Up    |   22-Jan-15   |   22-Feb-15   |   
Check-Up    |   21-Jan-15   |   21-Jan-1    |
```

I need to find the diff bw 19 feb of End date and 27 jan of Start date . A simple datediff is not working. can someone help now ?

Comment: Do you see a picture here? You can't show a picture by including the binary data in a post.

Comment: lol... I know.. I wonder why StackOverflow is dis-allowing me to post pics until I get 10 points... I am badly in need of a help. Can you refer me some other web address where I can post this question and picture ?

Comment: Try to post the question as text instead of a picture. Don't know what's in the picture, but if it has a lot of text in it, you shouldn't post it as a picture.

Comment: Is that all the Data is structured as? Does it have any ID?

Comment: yes, Paulfransis.. all I require is a query...